# Accessing Amazon ec-2 instance from the web

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have to do part of a college project on amazon instance. The lecturer set up the instances for the year, supplying us with the public DNS and KEY.

Having downloaded WINSCP to make it easier etc. I find that after i have created my html pages etc i cannot access them from the web.

IM assuming that that http://ec2-***-***-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home.html should open the file ???

Any help would be apprciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download PuTTy and configure it to access your ec2 instance on terminal. Install any web server e.g Apache or you can install LAMP directly to make your file accessible on web.

Comment: i ran httpd -v to see if apache was installed. it is, as is php and mysql... still nothing

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1. `httpd -v` will tell you what version of http is installed. But it doesn't tell you whether or not its running. Use `service httpd status` to see if its running.
2. Check the apache config file and make sure you put the index.html file in the correct directory.
3. Verify that you can access port 80 from outside the instance. Its possible there is a firewall in amazon that the professor has not unlocked.